# Branch merging, showing all changes

Tags: mercurial

Ok, I have a mercurial repository.

I create a new branch to develop a new feature over a few days.

Every day, I check in all the current progress, but as the development is very fluid, I don't want to spend a lot of time writing meticulous notes on what the changes are, as there is a very real possibility that they will get re-written/ removed later on. So I just generally write a brief "Spent a bit of time on the algorithm" or "tweaked a lot of boiler plate code" etc.

Now, when the feature is complete, or at a stage where it is stable enough to fold back into the trunk (which for arguments sake has had no changes since I branched) actioning a merge simply seems to copy all the changes back to the trunk, but without showing the pure differences between the branch head and the trunk.

Is there any way to force this type of behavior short of deleting the branch (and thus losing all history of development)?

Answer (score 0):

After typing `hg merge` (but before committing), try `hg diff -r'p1():p2()'`.